# SAS NOTSORTED Equivalent

Tags: sas, wrds-compusat, wrds

I was using the following code to analyze data:

```
 set taq.cq_&yyyymmdd:;
 by symbol date time NOTSORTED ex;
```

There are are thousands of datasets I am running the code on in the unit of days. When &yyyymmdd only specifies one dataset (for one day. for example, 20130102), it works. However, when I try to run it for multiple datasets (for example, 201301:), SAS returns the following errors:

```
BY NOTSORTED/NOBYSORTED cannot be used with SET statement when
more than one data set is specified.
```

If I cannot use NOTSORTED here, what is an equivalent statement that I could use?

My understanding of the keyword NOTSORTED is that you use it when the data is not sorted yet. Therefore, do I need to sort it first? How to do it?

I am also confused by the number of variables that NOTSORTED is referencing. Does it only have an effect on "time", or it has effect on "symbol, data, time"?

Many thanks!

UPDATE#2:

The rest of the process immediately following the set statement is: (pseudo code as i don't have the permission to post the original code)

```
Data _quotes;

SET STATEMENT HERE 

Change the name of a variable in the dataset (Variable name is EXN). 

last.EXN in a if statement. If the condition is satisfied, label EXN. 

Drop some variables. 

Run; 

DATA NEWDATASET (sortedby= SYMBOL DATE TIME index=(SYMBOL)
              label="WRDS-TAQ NBBO Data");

SET _quotes;
by symbol date time;

.... 

Run;
```

Comment: How big are your datasets?

Comment: 30 Gigabytes for each dataset. There are around 82500 of datasets in total. But as a test, I am only running 30 datasets now. @Reeza

Comment: Sorts would definitely be restrictive then. You would need to explain rest of process to suggest alternatives. Note the last piece of my answer and that this would likely interleave the datasets not append them.

Comment: @Reeza Is it possible for me to SET the dataset, sort it by symbol date time, and then set the datasets again by symbol date time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTSORTED means that SAS can assume the sort order in the data is correct, so it may not have explicitly gone through a PROC SORT but it is in logical order as listed in the BY statement.

All variables in the BY statement are included in the NOTSORTED option. Given that I suspect you fully don't understand BY group processing. 
It's usually a bit dangerous to use, especially if you don't understand BY group processing. If your data is in the same group but not adjacent it won't work properly and will not produce an error. The correct workaround depends on your processes to be honest.

I would suggest reviewing the documentation regarding BY group processing. It's quite in depth and has lots of samples to illustrate the different type of calculations.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n138da4gme3zb7n1nifpfhqv7clq.htm

NOTSORTED is often used in example posts to either avoid a sort or when using a custom sort that's difficult to implement in other ways. Explicitly sorting will remove this issue but you may also be misunderstanding how SAS processes data when you have a SET statement with a BY statement. I believe this is called interleaving.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/69852/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1tgk0uanvisvon1r26lc036k0w7.htm

Comment: If I drop the NOTSORTED statement, would sas sort them with the by keywords? This is actually the code someone else wrote, I am just trying to implement it on multiple datasets.

Comment: When I drop the NOTSORTED statement, the error becomes "ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set TAQ.CQ_20130102."

Comment: My understanding is, probably the variables are in groups but just not sorted. But NOSORTED statement seems to not work on multiple datasets. So I am not sure what should I do here ...

Comment: Once you SET multiple datasets AND have a BY statement it's no longer an APPEND it's an interleave. It may work but you'd have to test it thoroughly or someone else (more knowledgeable than me) can explain otherwise. AFAIK, unfortunately this methodology is not extendable to multiple datasets within a single step. If you have no computational restrictions I would say, append them all, sort, and them do whatever you were intending to do. Like I stated above, without further details of what you're trying to do, I can't make further suggestions.

Comment: Please see Update #2 about further steps I am doing.

Comment: If all you're doing is changing a variable name and label then you shouldn't be using a data step. You should be using PROC DATASETS. A data step forces you to reprocess all the data. PROC DATASETS will change the table information but not reprocess the data.

Comment: Can you set the multiple datasets together with BY if you remove the NOTSORTED keyword?  What about if you also remove the last variable in the BY statement?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the NOTSORTED keyword is being using to find groups for observations with the same value for the EX variable within the same symbol,date,time.  If you only need to find the FIRST then you can use the LAG() function to calculate the FIRST.EX flag.

```
data want;
  set taq.cq_&yyyymmdd:;
  by symbol date time;
  first_ex = first.time or ex ne lag(ex);
```

Otherwise then perhaps you want to convert the process to data step views and then set the views together.

```
data work.view_cq_20130102 / view=work.view_cq_20130102;
  set taq.cq_20130102;
  by symbol date time ex NOTSORTED;
  ...
run;
...
data want ;
  set work.view_cq_201301: ;
  by symbol date time;
...
```

Comment: But do I have to hard code different datasets as views? There are ten of thousands of them by the way ...

Comment: Also if I drop the NOTSORTED statement the error would become "ERROR: BY variables are not properly sorted on data set"

Comment: If the individual datasets are not sorted by SYMBOL DATE TIME then you need to better explain your whole process if you want help in finding an optimal solution.  Also why the heck do you have thousands of individual SAS datasets?